# Detect if browser is buffering audio stream from mixcloud

Tags: javascript

My app embeds [mixcloud's](http://www.mixcloud.com/) player widget. It's an embedded swf.

```
<object>
<embed src="http://www.mixcloud.com/media/swf/player/mixcloudLoader.swf?feed=x">
</embed>
</object>
```

If audio is presently streaming, then I want to alert any user who might click on one of my site's internal navigation links that the buffer will be lost if they continue.

Is there a way to detect whether or not the browser is buffering (or *has* finished buffering) a particular stream?

I think I need to distinguish between the objects that initialize the player (on page load), and the actual audio itself so that this alert only appears if the user has something playing or buffering.

Is there a js library that can help me here?